# C++ incorrect arithmetic results

Tags: c++, math, hex

I am writing a program using visual studios express for desktop.  The portion of the program giving me trouble is made to take a hex value which is a fraction of 2^32 and convert it to an integer value and perform some simple math on it (multiplication and division) using the following bit of programming.

```
    if (ch == 'z')
    {
        std::string r, d;
        unsigned int ra;
        unsigned int dec, n = 1;
        r = readline;
        while (n < 9)
        {
            r = r + buffer[0];
            n++;
            ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
        }
        ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
        n++;
        while (n > 9 && buffer[0] != '#')
        {
            d = d + buffer[0];
            n++;
            ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);
        }
        std::cout << "\n hex RA=" << r << " Hex Dec=" << d << "\n";



        std::stringstream ss,dd;
        ss << std::hex << r;
        ss >> ra;
        dd << std::hex << d;
        dd >> dec;

        std::cout << "\n ra=" << ra << " dec=" << dec << "\n";
        double RA = (ra * 86400);
        double DEC = (dec * 1296000);

        std::cout << "\n RA=" << RA << " DEC=" << DEC << "\n";
        double rRA = (RA / pow(2,32));
        double dDEC = (DEC / pow(2,32));

        std::cout << "\n RA=" << rRA << " DEC=" << dDEC << "\n";
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
 hex RA=1180C1E00 Hex Dec=0EA8A900

 ra=3435973836 dec=245934336

 RA=4294898176 DEC=1376419840

 RA2=0.999984 DEC2=0.320473
```

The correct values should be: (* next to values which are incorrect)

```
 hex RA=1180c1e00  HEX Dec=0ea8a900

 *ra=4698414592    dec=245934336

 *RA=40594302074880   *DEC=318730899456000

 *RA2=94515.9748...   *DEC2=74210.3204727...
```

I've thought using long int might fix the problem, but it gave the same results.  I also tried using the double type for the values which gave equally bizarre results.  If you can also explain why one hex conversion worked and the other didn't I would appreciate that.   I am new to C++ and realize there might be something I caveat I missed when going through the many tutorials for C++.  (note dec means declination, not decimal and has nothing to do with the code).

Comment: `ra==3435973836==0xCCCCCCCC`, which is the debugger's way of saying "uninitialized variable". Apparently, `ss >> ra` fails. Which compiler, which OS, are you building 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Please post the actual code (for example, the first `cout` shouldn't be outputting hexadecimal values and `ra` and `dec` are undeclared).  Also the values you're looking to get are outside of the range of the typical `unsigned int`.

Comment: You *do* initialize `r` and `d` somewhere in your actual code, before you use them?

Comment: Sorry I was editing out some stuff I put in for debugging purposes.  The code with all variables is now up.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am using visual studios express for desktop to compile.  Writing it as a Win32 console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are working on a platform where `unsigned int` is 32 bits large. `0x1180C1E00` doesn't fit into 32 bits. `ss >> ra` encounters an overflow when trying to parse this string, and fails. `ra` remains uninitialized; any further actions on it exhibit undefined behavior.

Also, change

```
double DEC = (dec * 1296000);
```

to

```
double DEC = (dec * 1296000.0);
```

As written, you perform arithmetic on two integers, then convert the result to double. But the result doesn't fit into `unsigned int`, and is wrapped around modulo 2^32 - before conversion. The change I propose converts `dec` to double, then performs multiplication in floating point.

---

With MSVC, `unsigned long` is 32 bits large, just like `unsigned int`. Using `unsigned long long` all around should help - it is 64 bits large.

Answer (score 1):

```
 hex RA=1180C1E00 Hex Dec=0EA8A900
```

If you can take that values as a string then the program below works as you want.

```
 unsigned long long int ra,dec;
stringstream ss,dd;
ss << hex << "1180C1E00";
ss >> ra;
dd << hex << "0EA8A900";
dd >> dec;

cout << "\n ra=" << ra << " dec=" << dec << "\n";
unsigned long long int RA = (ra * 86400);
unsigned long long int DEC = (dec * 1296000);

cout << "\n RA=" << RA << " DEC=" << DEC << "\n";
double rRA = RA/(pow(2.0,32));
double dDEC = DEC/(pow(2.0,32));
cout << "\n RA2=" << rRA << " DEC2=" << dDEC << "\n";
return 0;
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: I get the output from a serial port.  Thanks for pointing out I needed long long int to fit the values.